# Temperature of gas leaking into chambers

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

An initially evacuated and thermally isolated chamber has a small hole opened in its side through which an ideal gas effuses from the outside. The gas outside is at standard temperature and pressure.

A second, smaller hole directly opposite the first hole on the opposite side of the first chamber lets gas into a second evacuated and thermally isolated chamber. The initial temperature of the gas entering the second chamber, when the first hole is opened, is the same as the temperature for the gas in the first chamber.

Why this is the case?

Edit: Note that the hole is considered to be smaller than the mean free path.  Thus, the gas will not be able to reach equilibrium with the surroundings.

Comment: Why should only the initial temperature be the same?

Answer (score 1):

The temperature of the ideal gas will be the same at all times in all chambers whose walls are maintained at the standard temperature or are thermally isolated. The expansion of an ideal gas into vacuum doesn't perform any work therefore there is no temperature change.

Comment: Firstly, I'm sorry I didn't make myself clear: I'm considering the case where the hole which the gas effuse through is much smaller than the mean free path.  As a result, the gas will never reach equilibrium.  The effused gas will have a non-Maxwellian distribution as shown in page 22 of my professor's lecture notes: https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/AlexanderSchekochihin/A1/2014/A1LectureNotes.pdf